# Balancing queues in RollerCoaster Tycoon?

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon

Whenever I build two identical rides with queues, peeps will favor one of the rides over the other. This can cause problems with synchronized coasters.

I only have RollerCoaster Tycoon 3, but the problem seems to be common to the series.

Why do peeps behave like this and how can I balance the visitor numbers of the rides?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do your best to put the entrances to both queues right next to each other.  A lot of times if the line is too long, they'll leave.  But based on the same set of interests they'll go into the other line.  The alternative is to do a promotion for the ride that isn't getting enough attention to try to balance it out.

Answer (score 3):

No. The reason they do this is because one was built before the other, so they go to that one, and secondly it is normally closer.

Havn't found a fix for this.

Comment: Could you get around that by making the paired coasters into a single ride with two distinct embark points?  I know that was possible in roller coaster tycoon 1

Comment: Yes, but the problem still arises, because one entrance is further than the other.

What you could do however is probably put both in the middle so people come from either side, rather than along a path so they all come from one side, if this makes sense?

Comment: What about equidistant from a T-intersection, one way leading to the entrance of one ride, and the other leading to the alternate entrance? That would make it equidistant from each other.

Comment: T-intersections don't work either, they usually go all into the first ride while the second one remains almost empty.